# $\sup x_n⩾x⟺∀ϵ>0 ∃n x_n⩾x−ϵ$

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following correct? $\sup x_n⩾x⟺∀_{ϵ>0} ∃_n x_n⩾x−ϵ$

I would say so. My doubt is from the RHS to LHS. Even with the equality, since we can get an $x_n$ as close as we want from $x$, the supremum must be at least as high as $x$, right?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Suppose $\sup x_n<x$. See what you can get.

Comment: @Jack, I would get that from a certain epsilon and smaller, every $x_n$ would be below x-$\epsilon$ . So, I would have proved.

Comment: Yes, the epsilon chosen in my answer, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, try using contrapositive: if the supremum was less than $x$, there would be $\epsilon$ such that $x-\epsilon$ was greater than all $x_n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sup_{n}x_{n} < x$, then $x_{n} < x$ for all $n$ by definition; so
$$
x_{n} < x - \frac{(x-\sup_{n}x_{n})}{2}
$$
for all $n$ (seeing this inequality geometrically could be easier for some);
then the "if" part follows.

Answer (score 1):

try to proof from RHS to LHS by contradiction: Assume $sup(x_n) <x$. That means  $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n < x$ or $x-x_n > \delta$ for some $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$. This is already a contradiction the the RHS.